# Android: ¿como activar botones presionando y deslizando por la pantalla con ACTION_MOVE?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

Estoy trabajando en un piano y mi duda es de como activar mas botones (teclas) manteniendo presionado el táctil de la pantalla sin soltar y se activen mas botones al pasar por ellos, llegue hasta aquí personalice el `action_down` y `action_up`, pero no puedo personalizar el `action move`  o hay otra manera:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){



            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.p1:
                    soundPool.play(c3,1,1,0,0,1);
                    buttonC3.setScaleX(0.90f);
                    buttonC3.setScaleY(0.90f);

                    break;
                case R.id.b1:
                    soundPool.play(c3black,1,1,0,0,1);
                    buttonC3black.setScaleX(0.90f);
                    buttonC3black.setScaleY(0.90f);
                    break;

                 }
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    switch (v.getId()){
                        case R.id.p1:
                            buttonC3.setScaleX(1.0f);
                            buttonC3.setScaleY(1.0f);

                            break;
                        case R.id.b1:
                            buttonC3black.setScaleX(1.0f);
                            buttonC3black.setScaleY(1.0f);
                            break;
                    }

                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){


                    }


        }else;

        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

con el objecto MotionEvent que se crea en el onTouch, es decir el "event" que tienes aqui

```
......(View v, MotionEvent event)
```

si lo metes dentro del

```
  if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
  }
```

con los metodo **getX()** y **getY()**, puedes obtener la posicion de la pulsación, incluso la posicion de la esquina superior izquierda del objecto/botón, es decir, con esto:

```
event.getX()
event.gety();
```

obtienes las coordenadas del dedo, y con esto

```
nombreboton.getX();
nombreboton.getY();
```

obtienes las coordenadas de la esquina superior izquierda del boton, pero existe un problema ya que debes calcular el ancho y alto del boton y agregarselo mediante una formula a estas coordenadas, si no recuerdo mal las formulas son

```
nombreboton.getX()+anchoboton;
nombreboton.getY()+altoboton;
```

y luego con un if(), comprobar si las coordenadas del dedo estan entre este rango de datos , que da como resultado estas formulas.

Comment: Mi duda es ejecutar un codigo, el cual es activar y desactivar botones, cuando se arrastra el dedo por pantalla y se pasa por esos botones, te agradeceria si me ayudas en esto, gracias.

Comment: ya te lo he corregido